# External text file not loading on deployed site

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Hello there I'm trying to fill an html paragraph with text from a .txt file in order to be able to edit the paragraph from the text file instead of editing it on the code, I am using jQuery  when I ran the website using VS Code live server it renders perfectly but when I deployed the site using vercel the text does not show and inthe dev tools says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () text/intro-p1.txt:1". I have no idea why it works with live server and not when I deploy the page.

Deployed site:
[image]

Using live server:
[image]

```js
//JS Code

  function ajax(method, url, data, success, error) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) return;
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        success(xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      } else {
        error(xhr.status, xhr.response, xhr.responseType);
      }
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }

  //load text function 

  jQuery.get('text/intro-p1.txt', function(data) {
    //First paragraph of main page introduction
    $('#intro-p1').html(data.replace('n',''));
 });

 jQuery.get('text/intro-p2.txt', function(data) {
  //Second paragraph of main page introduction
  $('#intro-p2').html(data.replace('n',''));
});

//P.S I also tried changing 'text/intro-p2.txt' to '/text/intro-p2.txt' 
//To see if the path was incorrect but had no result there
```

```html
<!-- HTML code -->

    <section id="about">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="big-heading"><i>ACCURATE SOLUTIONS CORP.</i></h1>
            <p id="intro-p1" class="company-description"></p>
            <p id="intro-p2" class="company-description"></p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Project file Hierarchy

[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Does remote directory start with capital `T`? Have you tried using that in pathname? You can debug this a bit easier by trying to open that file from browser address bar also

Comment: You are absolutely right @charlietfl it was that I had the path wrong, it was /Text/intro-p1.txt thank you very much!